# C# public is not vaild???, Program does not contain a definition?

Tags: c#, tcpclient

Okay so I have a Console application that has a defualt Program.cs file and a extra class file I created named Client.cs but im having issues making a function public to be bale to call it.

I need (public static void BroadcastMessage(string message)) to be public but for some reason i get this = Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State Error CS0106 The modifier 'public' is not valid for this item ChatterServer C:\Users\Indigo\source\repos\Chatter\ChatterServer\Program.cs 42 Active
Program.cs

```
using ChatterServer;
using ChatterServer.Net.IO;
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;

namespace ChatterServer
{
    class Program
    {
        static List<Client> users;
        static TcpListener listener;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            users = new List<Client>();
            listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 4242);
            listener.Start();

            while (true)
            {
                var client = new Client(listener.AcceptTcpClient());
                users.Add(client);

                BroadcastConnection();
            }

            static void BroadcastConnection()
            {
                foreach (var user in users)
                {
                    foreach (var usr in users)
                    {
                        var broadcastPacket = new PacketBuilder();
                        broadcastPacket.WriteOpCode(1);
                        broadcastPacket.WriteMessage(usr.Username);
                        broadcastPacket.WriteMessage(usr.UID.ToString());
                        user.ClientSocket.Client.Send(broadcastPacket.GetPacketBytes());
                    }
                }
            }

            public static void BroadcastMessage(string message)
            {
                foreach(var user in users)
                {
                    var msgPacket = new PacketBuilder();
                    msgPacket.WriteOpCode(5);
                    msgPacket.WriteMessage(message);
                    user.ClientSocket.Client.Send(msgPacket.GetPacketBytes());
                }
            }
           
        }
    }
}
```

Then I need to be able to call the function from this file with (Program.BroadcastMessage(msg);) I get this error = Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0117  'Program' does not contain a definition for 'BroadcastMessage'  ChatterServer   C:\Users\Indigo\source\repos\Chatter\ChatterServer\Client.cs    43  Active

But im pretty sure I just need the Program.cs function to be public for this to work anyway?
Client.cs

```
using ChatterServer;
using ChatterServer.Net.IO;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;



    class Client
    {
        public string Username { get; set; }
        public Guid UID { get; set; }
        public TcpClient ClientSocket { get; set; }
        PacketReader packetReader;
        public Client(TcpClient client) 
        { 
            ClientSocket = client;
            UID = Guid.NewGuid();
            packetReader = new PacketReader(ClientSocket.GetStream());

            var opcode = packetReader.ReadByte();
            Username = packetReader.ReadMessage();
            

            Console.WriteLine($"[{DateTime.Now}]: Client has connected with username: {Username}");
        }

        void Process()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                try
                {
                    var opcode = packetReader.ReadByte();
                    switch (opcode)
                    {
                        case 5:
                            var msg = packetReader.ReadByte();
                            Console.WriteLine($"[{DateTime.Now}]: Message received... {msg}");
                            Program.BroadcastMessage(msg);
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                }
                catch ( Exception )
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"[{UID.ToString()}]: Disconnected...");
                    ClientSocket.Close();
                    throw;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Not sure what to do from here

Comment: basiclly i need it to be set to public but it dont want to be public and i dont know why

Comment: move the method outside of the Main() method ....

Comment: Typo?  You're trying to create methods inside of a method instead of at the class level.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 rules of importance here:

- A method that is nested inside another method can never be public, it is private to the method that contains it.
- A method (or any member) of a class can only be made `public` if the class is also `public`. But since the class has no modifier specified explicitly, `internal` is applied by default to the class, so it's members can not be more visible than that.